# In MongoDB, can I project whether a value has a substring to a new field?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In MongoDB, I want to group my documents based on whether a certain field has a certain substring. I was trying to project each document to a boolean that says whether the field has that substring/matches that pattern, and then group by that field.

How can I do this?

Edit:

1) I have tried the aggregation pipeline as

```
db.aggregate([
   { 
      '$match': { 
          '$regex': '.*world'
      }
   }
])
```

But I get an error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'test'), ('pipeline', [{'$match': {'$regex': '.*world'}}])]) failed: exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $regex
```

2) I am NOT trying to select only the words that match the pattern. I would like to select every document. I would like to make a field called 'matched' which says whether the pattern was matched for each element.

Comment: Are you asking about MongoDB [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)?

Comment: You can aggregate your collection documents and find which ones ``match`` a given ``$regex``

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your docs look like and which field you're trying to look for matches in?

Answer (score 1):

The [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator needs to appear after the field that you are matching on:

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { 
      "fieldName": {"$regex": ".*world"}
    }
  }
])
```

The "unknown top level operator" message means that the operator has to appear *after* the field to which it applies.

Comment: I am not trying to select only the objects that match the regex.
I am trying to project the same set of objects, and generate a field that states whether the regex matched or not.