# MongoError unknown top level operator: $set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I do this:

```
return scores.updateQ({_id:score._id},
{
    $set:{"partId":partId,"activityId":activityId},
    $unset:{topicType:'',topicId:'',courseId:''}
},
{strict:false})
```

Where `partId` and `activityId` are variables, defined elsewhere,

I get

```
{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'unknown top level operator: $set',
  index: 0,
  code: 2,
  errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $set' }
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824973/in-mongodb-can-i-project-whether-a-value-has-a-substring-to-a-new-field/25859257#25859257) says

> "The "unknown top level operator" message means that the operator has
>   to appear after the field to which it applies."

But [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) says you can do it the way I'm doing it

So maybe there's something else wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the syntax for the wrong [update method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update). You should be using [this method's](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) syntax, assuming that `scores` is a document.

```
return scores.updateQ({
    $set: { "partId": partId, "activityId": activityId},
    $unset: { topicType: '', topicId: '', courseId: ''}
},
{ strict: false });
```

Also, in Mongoose, it uses `$set` by default, so this should be equivalent:

```
return scores.updateQ({
    partId: partId,
    activityId: activityId,
    $unset: { topicType: '', topicId: '', courseId: ''}
},
{ strict: false });
```

EDIT:

My assumption is that `scores` is a document (an instance of the Model):

```
var schema = new Schema({});
var Scores = mongoose.model('Scores', schema);
var scores = new Scores({});
```

Both `Scores.update` and `scores.update` exist, but the syntax is different, which may be what's causing your error. Here's the difference:

```
// Generic update
Scores.update({ _id: id }, { prop: 'value' }, callback);

// Designed to update scores specifically
scores.update({ prop: 'value' }, callback);
```

NOTE:

If these assumptions are not correct, include more context in your answer, like how you got there.

Comment: Is an "instance of a Model" a `Model`, or is it a `document`? I can call `find()` on `scores` to query for documents, so that means it's a Model, right?

Comment: I updated to clarify language and add more depth. I don't know the ins and outs of how inheritance works in Mongoose, but it's possible, I don't know, that if you call `scores.find()`, it goes up the prototype until it finds `find()` at `Scores.find()`, so it works. However, there are conflicting update methods here, which is your problem.